# MaterialCalendarView Dotspan not appearing

Tags: android

I'm using this library: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview in my project. Here are segments of my code. I used the EventDecorator class that was provided in the documentation for the Dot Span and renamed it. The calendarView is a MaterialCalendarView in the EventFragment. I wanted to add a Dot Span whenever I click on a specific date in the calendarView, but it doesn't seem to be working/showing up. **markedDates** is an array list containing all the CalendarDay that were clicked on, so every time I click on a specific date in the calendarView, I add the CalendarDay to the array list. Does anyone know how to fix this/make it work?

```
public class CurrentDayDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {

    private final int color;
    private final HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

    public CurrentDayDecorator(int color, Collection<CalendarDay> dates) {
        this.color = color;
        this.dates = new HashSet<>(dates);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
        return dates.contains(day);
    }

    @Override
    public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
        view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
    }
}
```

In EventFragment class

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
                markedDates.add(date);

                currentDayDecorator = new CurrentDayDecorator(Color.WHITE, markedDates);
                widget.addDecorator(currentDayDecorator);
                widget.invalidateDecorators();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already too late but my solution can be beneficial for a lot more as I myself couldn't find a good implementation of adding dots. I will be showing a simple implementation of putting a red color dot on all those dates where user gonna click and I believe you can customise things accordingly. So, here we go.

First thing first, make a new java class "EventDecorator" and copy all the following code inside that-

```
public class EventDecorator extends AppCompatActivity implements DayViewDecorator {

 private final int color = Color.parseColor("#FF0000");
 private final CalendarDay dates;

 public EventDecorator(CalendarDay dates) {

    this.dates = dates;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
     return dates==day;
 }

 @Override
 public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
     view.addSpan(new DotSpan(5, color));
 }
}
```

Now come to the fragment where we will be setting up the onDateChangegListener, So, copy all this code there inside the createView-

```
  CalendarView calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);     //remove view. if it's an activity
  calendarView.setOnDateChangedListener(new OnDateSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSelected(@NonNull MaterialCalendarView widget, @NonNull CalendarDay date, boolean selected) {
           
            EventDecorator  eventDecorator= new EventDecorator(date);
            widget.addDecorator(eventDecorator);
            widget.invalidateDecorators();

        }
    });
```

So this is how things are working and if you want to use these dots only on those dates with some events then you can make an array of these dates, store them and then pass them to the EventDecorator class.
Hope this helps someone. Be free to ask anything.